# Nuxt 3 + electron issue

Tags: javascript, electron, nuxtjs3

I'm using Nuxt 3 with electron. I managed to create dev server with electron, but I can't build it. Every time I build it it doesn't see the index.html file(1st screen).
[image: Error in loading file]

Here is the path:

[image: file]

I tried a lot of variants of path in electron.js, but nothing worked. Also, I am attaching screens with my code.

nuxt.config.ts
[image]

electron.js
[image]

package.json
[image]

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. See [ask].

Comment: Hi, please do not add code screenshots but rather use actual text. Also, does it give you any error when building or it fails silently?

Comment: No, error when building

Comment: I suppose the issue is in path in electron.js

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the problem may be in the work of vue-router, you need to change the router from historyMode to hashHistoryMode